# list slicing syntax python if only one element in list

Tags: python, pandas, list, slice

In the following dataframe i want to select each element except for the last:

```
  df3=pd.DataFrame({'text':[[['   Macquarie Research '],
 ['   Susquehanna Financial Group', ' LLLP', ' Research Division ']],[['   Goldman Sachs Group Inc.', ' Research Division '],
 ['   Citigroup Inc', ' Research Division ']]]})
df3.head()
```

to do the selection i call

```
df3.text=[[a[:-1]for a in i]for i in df3.text]
```

in my understanding this should select every element except for the last. What i dont understand is that if there is only one element in the list (like Macquarie Research) it returns an empty list
e.g the output of `df3.text[0]` is `[[], ['   Susquehanna Financial Group', ' LLLP']]`

How can i perform this operation but keep the list if there is only one element?
Am i making some obvious mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
 [[a[:-1] if len(a) > 1 else a for a in i] for i in df3.text]
```

Comment: didnt think about conditionals in the comprehension^^ thanks :) but just out of curiosity why is the code returning an empty list if there is only one element?

Comment: Your code, you mean? Because when there's only a single element, that one is also the last, so your expectation of removing the last element is indeed satisfied.